# How to Convert JSONString to JSONArray using Json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am trying to convert the JSONString value to the JSONArray for further processing.
Currently my JSONString value comes as

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

now all I need is to convert this JSONString to JSON Array so that I can easily iterate over the values.
How can we achieve this using Json4s

Comment: Are you saying you have a JSONString whose value can also be parsed as JSON? Something like `{"data": "[1,2,3]"}` ? Can you show the complete input JSON document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val a= "[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"]"
val b = parse(a)
val c = b.values.asInstanceOf[List[String]]
for (d <- c) {
  println(d)
}
```